# How to use Multiple Authentication Providers with Firebase In Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How do i link multiple Sign providers like google AND Facebook into on Activity so that the user can use any of them?

Comment: You can use multiple authentication & after login you need to store email id/ mobile number by using Cloud Functions in Firebase database.

Comment: How do i do that and save data into firebase realtime database

Comment: Please checkk this https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: Check Firebase official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui

Comment: To link the credentials of a single user on multiple providers, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

Answer (score 0):

Learn from their official website. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui

Facebook account kit
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android

If you are having errors, then come back here.